# lambda function in c++ and inheritance

Tags: c++11, lambda

i'm new to lambda functions in c++ and am trying to make a simple one but have some problems. i've tried to make a heterogeneous container which include stacks, queues, and lists and one of the exercise is to make a lambda function which check if an element answers a specific condition defined as:

```
using Condition = bool (*)(T const&);
```

so here is a piece of my heterogeneous container:
For example for stacks:

```
template <typename T>
using Condition1 = bool (*)(T const&);

template <typename T>
class LinkedStack {
private:
    StackElement<T>* top;

public:
    LinkedStack();
    LinkedStack(LinkedStack const&);
    LinkedStack& operator=(LinkedStack const&);
    bool empty() const;
    bool member(T const& x);
    T peek() const;
    void push(T const&);
    T pop();
    ~LinkedStack();
};

template<typename T,typename Condition1>
bool q_filter(Condition1 func,LinkedStack<T>& s){
        LinkedStack<T> tmp;
        tmp = s;
       if((tmp).empty())
          return false;
       while(!tmp.empty()){
           if (func(tmp.peek()))
              return true;
            else
                tmp.pop();
       }
       return false;
}
```

the stack-object(which is need to perform object in h-container):

```
template <typename T>
class Object {
public:
    using Condition = bool (*)(T const&);
    virtual bool insert(T const&) = 0;
    virtual bool remove(T&) = 0;
    virtual bool member(T const&) = 0;
    virtual int l_size() = 0;
    virtual void sort() = 0;
    virtual bool special_condition(Condition);
    virtual void print(ostream& os) const = 0;
    virtual ~Object() {}

};

template <typename T>
class StackObject : public Object<T>, private LinkedStack<T> {
public:
    using Condition = bool (*)(T const&);

    // включване
    bool insert(T const& x) {
        LinkedStack<T>::push(x);
        return true;
    }

    // изключване
    bool remove(T& x) {
        if (LinkedStack<T>::empty())
            return false;
        x = LinkedStack<T>::pop();
        return true;
    }

    // проверка
    bool member(T const& x){
        return LinkedStack<T>::member(x);
    }

    int l_size() {
       return my_size(*this);
    }

    // извеждане
    void print(ostream& os) const {
        os << *this;
    }

    void sort(){
       s_sort(*this);
    }

    bool special_condition(Condition c){
          return q_filter(c,*this);
}
};
```

and main-function:

```
int main(){
    QueueStackList qsl;
    qsl.read_from_file();
    (*(qsl.begin()))->special_condition([](int x) -> bool { return x%2 != 0; });
    return 0;
}
```

QueueStackList is implemented like a linked-list and qsl.begin() returns
an iterator for the first element in the heterogeneous list;
when i compile it returns this kind of errors:

```
invalid user-defined conversion from 'main()::<lambda(int)>' to 'Object<int>::Condition {aka bool (*)(const int&)}' [-fpermissive]|
candidate is: main()::<lambda(int)>::operator bool (*)(int)() const <near match>|
no known conversion for implicit 'this' parameter from 'bool (*)(int)' to 'Object<int>::Condition {aka bool (*)(const int&)}'|
```

which i really don't know what mean ?

Comment: You are trying to pass a lambda that takes `int` parameter, to the callee that expects a function taking `int&`.

Comment: when i change to int const& it return this error: ||=== undentified reference to   `Object<int>::special_condition(bool (*)(int const&) )' which i don't understact why when condition is bool (*) (T const&) and in the heterogenius conteiner i've define stack-object like StackObject<int>

Comment: And indeed, nowhere in the code you've shown is `Object::special_condition` implemented. Did you mean to make it pure virtual, as you did with other members of `Object`?

Comment: After the function sort in the StackObject  i have :  
    bool special_condition(Condition c){
          return q_filter(c,*this);
}

Comment: Yes, you've implemented `StackObject::sepcial_condition` - but not `Object::special_condition`.

Comment: ooo i see , if i make it pure virtual like others ?

Comment: Yess , it works :) Big thanks @Igor Tandetnik